# RLException: Machine [ubuntu2] already added and does not match duplicate entry

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had a working multi-machine environment for a while but today I get this error that I cannot debug myself.

> RLException: Machine [ubuntu2] already
> added and does not match duplicate
> entry

I have set the following environment variables:

Machine 1 ubuntu1:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.2:11311
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.1
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.1
```

Machine 2 ubuntu2:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.2
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.2
```

In my launch file, I declare machine like:

```
<machine name="ubuntu2" address="10.0.0.2" env-loader="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/env.sh" user="ubuntu"/>
```

Machine 2 runs the roscore master node. The namespaces resolves in ssh (ssh ubuntu2). Machine1 runs the launch files. I am not sure what do to fix this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354734/rlexception:-machine-%5Bubuntu2%5D-already-added-and-does-not-match-duplicate-entry/) by [magnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/54538/magnus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-12**:
I'm not sure whether it's the cause, but in any case: do *not* set both `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_IP` (and don't set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to an IP). Use one or the other, in your case you should probably only set `ROS_IP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution is to check that all startup scripts that call the same  have the same configuration (in my case address).

One small launch file in the launch sequence had an old address, which is why I had duplicate entries which did not match.

---

Originally posted by [magnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/54538/magnus/) with karma: 33 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0